# Create a temporal network with toneto (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

I have the following dataframe (here is the portion of it):

```
{'date': {0: Timestamp('2020-10-03 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-10-03 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-10-03 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-10-03 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-10-24 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-10-24 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2020-10-24 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2020-10-24 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2020-10-25 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2020-10-25 00:00:00')},
 'from': {0: 7960001,
  1: 25500005,
  2: 4660001,
  3: 91000032,
  4: 280001,
  5: 26100016,
  6: 30001114,
  7: 12000016,
  8: 79000523,
  9: 74000114},
 'to': {0: 30000934,
  1: 74000351,
  2: 4660001,
  3: 91000031,
  4: 66000413,
  5: 26100022,
  6: 26100024,
  7: 12000016,
  8: 79000321,
  9: 74000122},
 'weight': {0: 17.1,
  1: 15.0,
  2: 931.6,
  3: 145.9,
  4: 29.3,
  5: 25.8,
  6: 15.0,
  7: 132.4,
  8: 51.5,
  9: 492.9}}
```

And I want to build a temporal network out of this time series - graph/network data.

I would like to build a network with respect to time + clusters.

Here is what I am trying to do:

`df` is the `dataframe` above

```
    import teneto
    t = list(df.index())
    netin = {'i': df['from'], 'j': df['to'], 't': t, 'weight': df['weight']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=netin)
    tnet = TemporalNetwork(from_df=df)
    tnet.network
```

Keep getting:

```
TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable
```

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Did you have any luck with your scikit-learn installation on your M1? Since you've deleted the question, I don't know if it worked (and how) or you gave up, and it would be some feedback to me to know the result, since I've put some time into helping.

Comment: @9769953 nope, people just downvoted it instead of figuring out how to solve it.
I have tried almost everything, nothing worked. The only think I will try to do is to do it with dockers and in parallel wait for official solution.
In any case we can connect and have a look on it together. My LinkedIn is Steve Solun.

Comment: If you delete your question, there is no chance anyone will answer it. That there are no answers doesn't mean you won't get an answer (for example, some people browse through specific tags once every few days for unanswered question).

Comment: Downvotes often indicate a badly posed question. If I remember correctly, you mentioned you couldn't install scikit-learn, followed by a (long-ish) error message. There was no information about what you had tried, what system (OS, chip (M1)) you were using. Further, deleting the question because it was downvoted suggests to me you care more about the votes than an actual solution.

Comment: If you decide to undelete your question, you can edit it with the new information given in the comments (system type, NumPy installs fine, SciPy does not); you could also indicate why other solutions don't work for you (e.g., there are several guides you can find about Conda installations of Scikit-learn on an M1). You may also want to trim the error messages, replacing very similar lines with ellipses. Since you would now have a scikit-learn installation error message, *and* a scipy installation error message.